# Different results for extract epoch on different PostgreSQL servers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

We convert time stamps to epoch, do some math on them and then convert them back to time stamps. All times in the database are `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

Since the switch to summer time here in the UK times are off by one hour on one server but not on the other so I did a little test:

```
SHOW SERVER_VERSION;
SHOW TIMEZONE;
SELECT extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01');
```

On one server I get

```
 server_version 
----------------
9.1.15
(1 row)

 TimeZone 
----------
GB
(1 row)

 date_part 
-----------
         0
(1 row)
```

But on the other

```
 server_version 
----------------
9.3.6
(1 row)

 TimeZone 
----------
GB
(1 row)

 date_part 
-----------
     -3600
(1 row)
```

Are there any server settings which could be causing this?

Or did the behaviour of `extract` change after Postgres 9.1?

Comment: A guess: Try `SELECT extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01'::timestamp with time zone);`

Comment: Generally the base that makes more sense in the context of the question  is `'1970-01-01'::timestamp at time zone 'GMT'`. Extracting epoch from that should work as expected in both pre-9.2 and post-9.2 versions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the behavior of `extract` changed in PostgreSQL version 9.2. From [the release notes:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2.html#AEN112278)

> - Make [`EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp without time zone)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) measure the epoch from local midnight, not UTC midnight (Tom Lane)
>
>   This change reverts an ill-considered change made in release 7.3. Measuring from UTC midnight was inconsistent because it made the result dependent on the [`timezone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) setting, which computations for `timestamp without time zone` should not be. The previous behavior remains available by casting the input value to `timestamp with time zone`.

This might be what is causing the difference, because according to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html),

> The SQL standard requires that writing just `timestamp` be equivalent to `timestamp without time zone`, and PostgreSQL honors that behavior.

As @unique_id suggests, using `timestamp with time zone` (a.k.a. `timestamptz`) should remove the inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks, using `::timestamp with time zone` as @unique_id suggested gives me -3600 on both servers. We convert back to timestamps after some  calculations so the whole thing is rather like `SELECT to_timestamp(extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01'::timestamp with time zone))::timestamp without time zone`.  Tried a few other things and `extract(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')` also seems to work.