# Wrong date display when using "date" data type in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, date, types

Some tables use the "date" datatype.  In the old system (psql 9.1/PHP5.3), when the date is stored in the database, it is stored correctly.  However, in the new system (psql 9.6/PHP 7.1), the date stored incorrectly.  For example, when storing 7/13/10 in the old system, it stores the following:

```
stage_date |      to_timestamp
------------+------------------------
1279004400 | 2010-07-13 00:00:00-07
```

When storing the same date in the new system, it stores the following:

```
 stage_date |      to_timestamp
------------+------------------------
 1278979200 | 2010-07-12 17:00:00-07
```

Both Operating systems are set to "America/Los_Angeles".  The old database is set to use "localtime" (which in 9.1 would use system timezone).  The new database uses "PDT".

What would cause the value in the old system to be set to "1279004400" vs "1278979200" in the new system?

Part of the table definition:

```
    Column    |           Type      
--------------+---------------------
 id           | integer             
 stage_date   | date
```

Comment: what time zone your client use?.. `show time zone`

Comment: The client uses PDT.

Comment: I would advise to use `timestamptz` to avoid mess with time zones, but you probably would if you could

Comment: I don't understand. The value 1279004400 is no legal value for the `date` data type.

Comment: The function extract(epoch from stage_date) as stage_date is used to convert the date from "2010-07-13" to 1279004400 .

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ends up here:  The table view was using the extract function to convert the date to an epoch.  The behavior of extract changed in PostgreSQL version 9.2.

> This change reverts an ill-considered change made in release 7.3.
>   Measuring from UTC midnight was inconsistent because it made the
>   result dependent on the timezone setting, which computations for
>   timestamp without time zone should not be. The previous behavior
>   remains available by casting the input value to timestamp with time
>   zone.

Please see the answer to the following question for more details:
[Different results for extract epoch on different PostgreSQL servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536542/different-results-for-extract-epoch-on-different-postgresql-servers)